# How to have telegram bot request users/chats from user when InlineKeyboardButton is clicked?

Tags: telegram-bot

I am currently trying to figure out if there is a way for the user to be shown a list of users/chats to select from when they click an InlineKeyboardButton as shown [here](https://telegram.org/blog/profile-pics-emoji-translations#chat-selection-for-bots).

I am aware that it is possible to do so with a regular KeyboardButton by creating and passing a KeyboardButtonRequestUser/KeyboardButtonRequestChat to the KeyboardButton as mentioned in the [documentation](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#keyboardbutton) but I cannot find anything that mentions how to do it with InlineKeyboardButtons. Is there any way to do it with an InlineKeyboardButton or is it not currently possible?

Comment: I just played with that kind of button a little, and seems like having it in an inline keyboard is not something that is possible, not even with the MTProto API directly. The video shown on Telegram’s website is misleading, given the fact.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.